# How to Remove Blank Space in Wordpress JSON API Response

Tags: json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

we will build an android app and it's backend wordpress CMS so we build API and when Hit this API on POSTMAN that JASOn format is good but when check in XML format that 4 line Blank Space in starting so How can i remove thats Blank Space?? See Attachment

http://dev.w3ondemand.com/coverati/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/space.png

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: this blank Space has All API's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow

It looks like one of your Theme files or one of your plugins throw empty lines.
In my experience I saw this many times where developers close their PHP files, and have some empty lines after it. For example:

```
    <?php 
some_php_code();
?>
{empty line}
{empty line}
{-- end of file--}
```

Better to not close the PHP file. Remove the closing ?> at the end of file.

Best way to check this:

1. first turn off all your plugins. and recheck if the lines removed.
2. if not removed. most chances are that one or more of your Theme files has empty line. Check you theme files